# Check if anchors are clicked or not

Tags: jquery, html, anchor

```
<a href='#' id='aId1'>1</a>
<a href='#' id='aId2'>2</a>
<a href='#' id='aId3'>3</a>
<a href='#' id='aId4'>4</a>
<a href='#' id='aId5'>5</a>
```

Is it possible to check if an anchor is clicked or not via JQuery? It should get the id of the clicked anchor, and if no anchor is clicked, it should also have an event to perform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will **only** trigger when an anchor is clicked on and stores the elements `id` as a variable.

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {

    // Id of the element that was clicked
    var elementId = $(this).attr("id");

});
```

If you want to prevent the default action when an anchor is clicked, add this to end of the function:

```
e.preventDefault(); return false;
```

If you want mark an anchor as clicked for future reference, try this:

```
$("a").on("click", function (e) {

    // Id of the element that was clicked
    var elementId = $(this).attr("id");

    $(this).data("clicked", true);

});
```

The, using jquery, check if it has been clicked using

```
$(element).data("clicked") // returns True or False
```

If you want to listen for everything being clicked and want to see if it was an anchor, try:

```
$("*").not("body").on("click", function (e) {

    if ($(this).is("a")) {
        // Id of the element that was clicked
        var elementId = $(this).attr("id");
    } else {
        // An anchor was not clicked, do something else
    }

});
```

Comment: I get it, but how will I check if no anchor is clicked?

Comment: @JetPro Updated answer. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

One way is just to add a clicked class when they are clicked.

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

Then you can just do stuff with the $(".clicked") selector.

Comment: Can you explain it? I dont know what a selector is. And can I check if no anchor is clicked?

Comment: A jquery selector (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) is basically the string you enter into the $() thing. When you say $("a") you are selecting anchors. The code I gave adds the class "clicked" to anchors that are clicked. You can then select for them with $(".clicked").